# Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic) Amazon Linux

Tags: ssh

I've looked at the other questions on this and none have worked for me.

I did the following to add a new user on an EC2 instance running Amazon Linux:

```
sudo usermod -G git_group rich
sudo mkdir -p /home/rich/.ssh
sudo mkdir /home/rich/.ssh/authorized_keys
sudo chown root:root /home/rich
sudo chown -R rich:rich /home/rich/
sudo chmod 700 /home/rich/.ssh
sudo chmod 700 /home/rich/.ssh/authorized_keys

sudo su rich

cd ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -a 100 -b 4096 -C "" -E sha256 -o -t rsa
 < no passwords >
cp id_rsa.pub ./authorized_keys
```

On the remote machine I got the keys via sftp and placed them in /home/my_user/.ssh, making sure both have chmod 600 permissions.

I then added an entry to .ssh/config:

```
User rich
IdentityFile = ~/.ssh/rich_private_key
```

When I try

`ssh -vvv rich@xxx.xxxx.xxx`

I get:

```
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/my_user/.ssh/rich_private_key
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA xxx
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
rich@xxx.xxxx.xxx: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Any idea what I'm missing?  I also added PubkeyAuthentication yes to sshd_config and restarted it, which did not appear to help.

Comment: Check syslog on the remote system to see if the ssh server is logging the reason that it isn't accepting the key.

Comment: Is your umask such that `ssh-keygen` (and/or `cp`) created `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` with more read-access than you want?

Comment: drw------- 2 rich rich   24 Oct 10 13:40 authorized_keys

Comment: @kenster I'm having difficulty finding a log which shows ssh activity - this is Amazon Linux.  /var/log/dmesg only has entries up to august for some reason.

Comment: -rw------- 1 rich rich 726 Oct 10 13:38 id_rsa.pub

Answer (score 0):

I had authorized_keys as a directory containing keys (which was incorrect), rather than a file which has each line being a key, which fixed it.